# Double Border Style is solid in Safari 9

Tags: css, safari, border

Is there a bug in Safari 9 that does not render `border-style: double`. I've created a [Pen](http://codepen.io/coold78/pen/rxBzyr) to test this: [View Pen](http://codepen.io/coold78/pen/rxBzyr)

Is anyone else seeing this and is there a fix?

Thanks

**UPDATE 1**

It looks like this problem with the border-width. A 3px border looks fine in Safari 9, but a 4px border looks solid.

I updated the Pen - [View Pen](http://codepen.io/coold78/pen/rxBzyr)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
border-color: black; 
border-style: double;
border-width: 0px 0px 3px 0px
```

or

```
border: 3px double black;
border-right-width: 0px;
border-left-width: 0px;
```

Pen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YwKxJw

Comment: Did you try this with a 4px border? It looks fine with a 3px border.

Comment: Safari interprets this as a two bold lines and they overlap. Use 3px.

Comment: Thanks Lukas. I guess if I need a wider double line, I would have to use `box-shadow` or pseudo elements.